# How can i acess data inside nested hashmap with dataholder?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have an hashmap with a dataholder inside, like this:

```
map.put(0, new Data("req", 5));
```

When i try to acess it, this is the print:

```
System.out.println("Print -> " + req.get(0));
```

> Req.get(count2) -> null

The hashmap is constructed like this.

```
1 Data{key='0|0|00|01|2|00|3', value=3}
```

How can i acess the key with the string "'0|0|00|01|2|00|3'" ?

Comment: `data.entrySet().stream().map(x -> (x.getKey() + "=" + x.getValue())).forEach(System.out::println);`:  map -> stream -> map -> foreach

Comment: `map.entrySet().stream().forEach(data -> System.out.println(data));`:  map -> stream -> map -> foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate in the Map Set and verify which Data object contains your key

In your case it would be:

```
public int findValue(Map mp, String key)
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        if(pair.getValue().getKey().equals(key));
            return pair.getValue().getValue();
        it.remove();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This function returns:

- the corresponding value if the key is found (only the first occurrence)
- -1 if the key cant be found

For this functions to work, you need to define [Getters](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp) for the Data object

Can't guarantee it works 100%, since I've not  tested it, at least it gives you an idea